# Rails tempfiles garbage collected before background processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, garbage-collection, delayed-job

I have an import method that I use to delay a CSV import with DelayedJob:

```
def import
  InventoryItem.delay.import_list(params[:file].path, current_vendor.id)
  redirect_to ...
end
```

If I'm not mistaken, passing the file param here creates a temp file that gets garbage cleaned at some point. My question is: when does this happen? Will it get cleaned when my Unicorn worker process gets killed?

Seems like there's a chance my tempfile gets cleaned before the background job starts processing it. Should I be uploading the file to S3 or something to prevent this, or is there a simpler way to avoid this issue? (I'm using CarrierWave and S3 in my app already).

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I ended up just uploading the files to S3 before processing them.

Comment: Thanks, me too. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29136640/1299792